Cant reach from databricks to Storage account
We are trying to make environemnt more secure and I have added the private endpoints to my storage account which is part of the Vnet-dev. My databricks is not Vnet injected but it has its own Workers-Vnet with its own private and public subnets.
I have made the Virtual network peering between two Vnets based on the documentaion!

On my datalake I have whitelisted my Own Vnet and expcted that sinse there is the peering between my own Vnet and databricks Vnet, I should have have been able reach storage account.
But I get belwo erro in databricks

This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403,
GET, https://mydatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/extract

Storage account has two PEP (blob and DFs) and as I said the subnet is whitelisted on the storage account.

can you check this once?

you are proposing to redeploy databricks in my own vnet  but I dont want to redeploy.

Error:

This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403, GET,https://mydatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/extract

To resolve the error You have to try to modify setting in ADLS like below:
Storage Accounts -> Your Storage Account you have created for ADLS -> Networking


Enabling the option "Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account" grants trusted Microsoft services permission to access the storage account.
Also make sure to have the required permissions like Contributor and User Access Administrator roles / Storage Blob Data  Owner role.
Assign the application to a role, make sure to assign the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the service principal.
Reference: Cant reach from databricks to Storage account

play_something_good can you check if the above solution helped you?

@play-something-good, there are two potential reasons for the error:
Databricks workspace to storage account connection: Please refer to the instructions shared by @Dileep Raj Narayan Thumula.
Access validation: Ensure your access to the storage account is properly configured (ACL, storage account key, SAS token, etc.).
Additionally, you could try changing the storage account network setting to "Enable from all networks".
Note: This is not a best practice for production workloads.
